# How to create a virtual file in linux (or block device) (through code, C/++ or Python) that I can hook into read/write/etc?

Tags: linux, filesystems, virtual, block-device

### Question

I've found similar questions on SO, but none of them answer the question or at least not in a relevant way.

Is it possible to have a file appear anywhere (in the FS, under /dev whatever), such that anybody can access it as if it were a file (or ideally a block device), but such that every read/write/access of that file is hookable so that I can catch the accesses, be it in C/++ or in python?

I'm aware of FUSE & VFS, but as I understand, both are for creating/emulating an entire file system, not just a single file or block-device.

I also see make-dev &  mknod being passed around, but nobody explains what you can actually do with mknod after "creating" the device node itself. How do I hook into accesses on that virtual node?

Basically, I need to re-route the accesses over a stream/socket, but it has to look/appear as a file, not a stream/socket, because those aren't seekable.

### ANSWER

Just use FUSE. It actually innately supports the very trivial process of hooking into a single file, and is supported in C/++ & Python. I'll upload a python example soon. Instead of creating/using a folder as a mountpoint, you use an empty file instead. Upon mounting, the file then has whatever size/contents you want it to, and it is read/writable, and each access triggers one of your fuse callbacks, which is perfect. you can even implement custom ioctl to make it look like a block device. Then on every access, your callbacks are always passed the same path as a target, which is "/", but that doesn't matter anyways since you are dealing with a single file anyways so you don't need it.

Comment: I can't really comment on much of this, but I believe with `mknod` you have to specify the major and minor numbers for the device. The major is used to identify the driver in the kernel to handle the device (e.g. which driver is ultimately used when doing reads/writes). See, e.g. https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ for confirmation. If I recall correctly, the major/minor numbers are discussed in the chapter on char device drivers.

Comment: There is [userspace block device driver](https://docs.kernel.org/block/ublk.html) in recent kernels.